# Error inflating class fragment in map on device only

Tags: android

I am getting "Error inflating class fragment" in my map activity.

I've looked at all the other suggestions for this error. Here is what doesn't make sense. It works in the emulator versions I have, but not on my device - Android version 5.1. The emulator version I have set up is the same API version as my device and it works on other emulators I have.

More frustratingly, it worked before on the device, and when I load older versions back onto my device, those versions no longer work. But they used to work on the device without this error!

Any ideas how that could possibly happen? I have deleted it from my phone and re-installed the older versions but they no longer work.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: You need to provide more code and a more detailed error message.

Comment: Did you add map API key to your manifest?? If so try creating new API key and try using it

Answer (score 0):

You use `Activity` or `FragmentActivity`(or `AppCompatActivity` extends from `FragmentActivity`). If you want activity contain fragment, you must use `FragmentActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work now.

The question was more about about why my app stopped working on my device, since there was no change in code. So I was doubtful it was anything with the code.

I reset my device and it works now. So Google play service must have had a problem on my phone.